# Unable to load local model via tensorflowjs model()

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have a model which I converted to json for tensorflowjs. Now I am trying to load this model from my local but its not able to load it and getting error
`Failed to load locally-saved model. TypeError: Cannot read property 'sourceLayer' of undefined`

I am using nodev8.16.0, tensorflow/tfjs:"^1.2.6" and @tensorflow/tfjs-node: "^1.2.5".
I tried to use various ways to load the model
tf.model()
tf.LayersModel()

Also tried to use `tfn.io.fileSystem` for loading the model

```
global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const tfn = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");

async function init() {
    const LOCAL_MODEL_PATH = 'file://some_model.json';
    // const handler = tfn.io.fileSystem(LOCAL_MODEL_PATH);
    let model;
    try {
        model = await tf.model(LOCAL_MODEL_PATH);
        model.summary();
        console.log('Loaded locally-saved model!');
        // runAndVisualizeInference(model);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Failed to load locally-saved model. ' + err);
    }
}
init();
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of `tf.model` is an object of symbolic tensor. An error is thrown because the right argument is not used. It is noteworthy to indicate that `tf.model` is used to build a new model. What is to be done here is to load an existing model saved in model.json.

```
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");
const tfn = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");
const handler = tfn.io.fileSystem("url-to-model.json");
const model = await tf.loadModel(handler);
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed this part in my question. I already tried this code as well but I am still getting the same error. ```Failed to load locally-saved model. TypeError: Cannot read property 'sourceLayer' of undefined```

Comment: In that case, change your question to reflect what you tried. Normally it should work. If it does not, you should provide more details about your python model and the command you use to convert to js